# How to use local library as requirement for pip

Tags: python, pip, setuptools

I have the following directory structure:

```
/pythonlibraries
  /libraryA
    setup.py
    libraryA/
        __init__.py
        alib.py
  /libraryB
    setup.py
    libraryB/
        __init__.py
        blib.py
```

blib.py:

```
import libraryA
```

setup.py for libraryB:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(name='libraryB',
      version='0.0',
      description='',
      packages=['libraryB'],
      install_requires=["ujson", "/pythonlibraries/libraryA"])
```

This doesn't work :/

How can I install local dependencies with pip?

Ideally I'd like to do pip install -e /pythonlibraries/libraryB and have it automatically install libraryA from my local disk.

Right now I have to install each local library individually manually...

Comment: I wonder if you can put a local path in dependency_links, or have them find each other with find_packages. Not an answer, just brainstorming. This message will self destruct.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to write full path like this
`install_requires=["ujson", "/home/user/pythonlibraries/libraryA"])`

Because "/" --> this is absolute directory